# Probability of multiple flips of a coin

Tags: probability

I am newbee to the probability and trying hard to learn probability. I am trying to solve the following question but dont have the clue how to approach the solution for this question. The question is

You flip a fair coin 12 times. What is the probability that it lands on one side twice the number of times it lands on
the other side.

Do I have to write down all the sample space and then find the probability ? or is there any shorter way.

Thanks

Comment: If it lands on one side twice the number of times it lands on the other side... then either there were eight heads and four tails, or four heads and eight tails.  Now... use the binomial distribution / binomial theorem / binomial coefficients, however you want to phrase it to find the probability of four heads out of twelve flips and the probability of eight heads out of twelve flips and add the results.

Comment: "*Do I have to write down all the sample space and then find the probability?*"  No, absolutely not.  The whole point of an introductory course in probability and combinatorics is to learn how to count in quick efficient manners without needing to resort to using your fingers and toes to count things.  You do not want to write down the entire sample space... there are $2^{12}=4096$ different sequences of coinflips here.  It would be a waste of time to try to write all four thousand outcomes out, not to mention highly prone to error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outcome whose probability is to be counted is landing 8 heads and 4 tails or 8 tails and 4 heads – one side shows up twice as often as the other in the 12 flips. The individual probabilities of either event occurring are given by the binomial distribution as
$$\binom{12}4(0.5)^{12}=0.12085$$
(the calculation is the same for 8H4T and 8T4H). Then since the two events are mutually exclusive, the final answer is obtained by adding the probabilities of the two events together, or doubling the previously obtained value, to yield $0.2417$.